# Set "Selected" Javascript from Dropdown List or combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code loads the list drop down, but the option isn't selected. How can I set a default selected option?

**Javascript:**

```
var options = '';
    options += '<option value="00">-- Pilih Salah Satu --</option>';
for (var s=0;s<json.kec.length;s++) {
    options += '<option value="' + json.kec[s].dist + '">'
            + json.kec[s].dist+json.kec[s].name + '</option>';
}
$("select#kecamatan").html(options);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ```$('select#kecamatan').empty().append(options);``` this will make the select dropdown empty and add the options in it.

Comment: What does "display selected" mean? Do you mean you want to set it so that one of the options that you are adding is selected by default?

Comment: I'm not sure, but from this I inferred that he wants to make one option be automatically selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this javascript is on a function, if it is:

```
    function getValues(default_value) {
                var options = '';
                options += '<option value="00">-- Pilih Salah Satu --</option>';
                for (var s=0;s<json.kec.length;s++) {
                    if(json.kec[s].dist == default_value) {
                        options += '<option value="' + json.kec[s].dist + '" selected>' + json.kec[s].dist+json.kec[s].name + '</option>';
                    } else {
                        options += '<option value="' + json.kec[s].dist + '">' + json.kec[s].dist+json.kec[s].name + '</option>';
                    }
                }
                $("select#kecamatan").html(options);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to have `$("select#kecamatan").html(options).val(default_value)` and skip the if/else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a if check for what value you want to make the option selected and in if section you need to add selected="selected" as **option** tag attribute

```
var options = '';
    options += '<option value="00">-- Pilih Salah Satu --</option>';
for (var s=0;s<json.kec.length;s++) {
if(your condition to make option selected)
    options += '<option value="' + json.kec[s].dist + '" selected="selected">'
            + json.kec[s].dist+json.kec[s].name + '</option>';
}
else if(your condition to make option not selected)
{
options += '<option value="' + json.kec[s].dist + '">'
            + json.kec[s].dist+json.kec[s].name + '</option>';
}
$("select#kecamatan").html(options);
```